Redirect issue of captive portal
Not able to redirect any intent URL to open any app(eg. playstore and appstore) from captive portal.
In captive portal if we give any intent urls as
window.location.href= intent:playstore-app-url
It asks for permission as the network you are trying to join is requesting to open other application - continue anyway via browser
But if we click on continue it opens the fallback url in the normal browser.
Can anyone explain why the intent is not getting resolve. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/intents
